# How can I prevent password protected pdfs from being converted online?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I have a website offering free downloadable pdfs. In order to protect the images and content in the pdfs I have password protected the files in Acrobat DC, but I've recently discovered that it's possible (and very easy) to convert the protected pdfs to word documents on some online pdf converters, allowing people to extract the images and other content. I currently have the security properties configured as follows:

- restrict editing and printing of document
- printing allowed
- no changes allowed
- enable copying of text, images and other content is unchecked
- enable text access for screen reader devices for the visually
  impaired is checked
- I have set a permissions password, and checked "encrypt all document
  contents except metadata"

Is the problem due to allowing text access for screen reader devices? I'd really like to know if there is any way I can prevent the protection from being bypassed so easily by these online converters! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Even with text access disabled what stops them from just opening your PDF and scraping the rendered page as images?

Comment: You're giving people the data. They need the data in order to see the document. If they have the data and they can see it, then they can do anything they want with it. Those "security flags" are only for compliant applications; if there exists an application that can read the data but ignores those flags… well… ‍♂️

Comment: OK, no way then. Understood.